# Firebase Storage not overwriting image

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage

I am trying to upload profile pictures to my firebase storage using swift.
The problem is that when the user posts a new profile picture, it doesn't overwrite the first one. On my app, it still shows the old one, even though on the database, it shows the new one is uploaded.

This is how I am loading the image

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()

let ref = storageRef.child("\(UserModel.docId)-ProfilePicture")

// check if file exists or not
ref.downloadURL { newUrl, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Image does not exist")
        self.profileImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
    } else {
        print("loaded database image")
        self.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: ref)
    }
}
```

This is how I am uploading the image.

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()
let photoRef = storageRef.child("\(UserModel.docId)-ProfilePicture")
let data = Data()


let uploadTask = photoRef.putFile(from: fileURL,metadata: nil) {(metadata,err)  in
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
        print("error uploading to database")
        return
    }
    print("Photo uploaded")
}
```

There are no errors.

Comment: Why not use `putData` with the raw jpeg data instead of `putFile`? I ask because the second code snippet is a bit confusing because you have a constant named `data` of type `Data` but never use it and opt to upload with `fileURL` which we don't see.

Comment: I'm not really sure, I just followed a tutorial, what would be the difference?

Comment: `putFile` is expecting a `URL` to a file path, which means you've saved the image somewhere on the user's device. `putData` is expecting `Data` which means you simply have the image in hand and have converted it to some desirable data type like jpeg data. How are you handling the image when the user selects one? And how do you successfully upload it the first time?

Comment: when the user selects the image, I convert the image from a uiImage to a dictionary, and then I do this with the data (the data is the dictionary) `if let editingImage = data[convertInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage)] as? UIImage` and then I do this `if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL` and run the upload to database function with the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to clear the cache before downloading the files, like this :

```
SDImageCache.shared.clearDisk()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is convert the `UIImage` to `Data` using the following `UIImage` method:

```
public func jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data?
```

You can call that function directly on your image to get back `Data` which you can then use to upload to Storage.

```
// handy extension
extension StorageMetadata {
    enum MetadataContentType: String {
        case jpeg = "image/jpeg"
    }
    
    convenience init(contentType: MetadataContentType) {
        self.init()
        self.contentType = contentType.rawValue
    }
}

let storage = Storage.storage()
let remotePath = "\(UserModel.docId)-ProfilePicture"
let metadata = StorageMetadata(contentType: .jpeg)

storage.reference(withPath: remotePath).putData(theJPEGData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
    if let _ = metadata {
        // success
    } else {
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        // failure
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how do I call the jpeg data and where?

Comment: @Marco.py First, get the image, maybe with `let theImage = maybeAnImageView.image`, and then get its data, such as `let jpegData = theImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)`. Then take `jpegData` and pass it into the Storage `putData(jpegData, metadata: metadata)` function.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I check the database and the new image is uploaded, but on my app it still shows the first image

Comment: I have the full code here. I changed the directory, i added a folder called ProfilePictures in the storage. https://dpaste.org/xDVOs

Comment: I would also like to add that I am running this on a real device, and when I run it on the simulator it actually shows the right image, super weird.